# MySQL driver installed but getConnection throws No suitable driver found

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, wildfly, mysql-connector

I have a fresh installed *Wildfly 10 application server* running in *standalone* mode. I need to deploy a project requiring the MySQL JDBC driver.
I installed the driver following the tutorial found at [JDBC Driver Setup](http://hpehl.info/jdbc-driver-setup.html) (I have chosen the module installation). After restarting WildFly, in **console.log** I read:

> INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService
>   Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver
>   class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
>   INFO [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-6)
>   WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql

It seems all good, but I can't get a connection for the database.
I'm using this piece of code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?user=someUser&password=somePass");
```

The first line throws the exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from [Module
>   "deployment.someProject-1.0.0.war:main
>   from Service Module Loader]"

If I comment out the first line, I get *No suitable driver exception*.

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advice

Comment: are you using maven ?

Comment: Yes i use Maven. ozOlip's answer solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a dependency for your WAR on the MySQL module you just created.

There are two ways, use a MANIFEST.MF file in the WAR with a line Dependencies: com.mysql

Or use a jboss-dependencies XML file like:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>

   <deployment>

      <dependencies>
         <module name="com.mysql" />
      </dependencies>

   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Both should be placed in the META-INF directory of the WAR file. There should be Maven plugins available to create both for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea.

As far as I know in WildFly modules are not seen to the apps by default.
And I suppose that you need to make your app know about the MySql module.

If you have WAR than need to create file jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF folder with content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="mysql" />      
    </dependencies>    
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: <module name="mysql" /> should be <module name="com.mysql" />